# Iteration happening outside of Iterator too in WSO2 EI 6.4.0/6.5.0

Tags: iterator, wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator

There is one `task scheduler` (count as `1`, interval `60` sec) which calls `proxy service` which establish connectivity to BigQuery API  and fetching Data from Bigquery Table and by using `Iterator` , iterate over elements and finally push modified payload to target endpoint.

**Data comes from bigQuery:**

```
{
 "kind": "bigquery#queryResponse",
 "schema": {
  "fields": [
   {
    "name": "Name",
    "type": "STRING",
    "mode": "NULLABLE"
   },
   {
    "name": "Age",
    "type": "INTEGER",
    "mode": "NULLABLE"
   }
  ]
 },
 "jobReference": {
  "projectId": "testbig-235116",
  "jobId": "job_GECobzPaLdbBW-SqIG-WrfOzaqtQ",
  "location": "US"
 },
 "totalRows": "2",
 "rows": [
  {
   "f": [
    {
     "v": "John"
    },
    {
     "v": "45"
    }
   ]
  },
  {
   "f": [
    {
     "v": "Harry"
    },
    {
     "v": "25"
    }
   ]
  }
 ],
 "totalBytesProcessed": "670",
 "jobComplete": true,
 "cacheHit": false
}
```

By using `Iterate Mediator` I am iterating over `JSON Array` Elements to push data to `service`.

Iterator-code:

```
<!--  Iterate over JSON Array Elements -->
    <iterate expression="$body//rows" id="BigQID">
        <target>
            <sequence>
                <property expression="//f[1]/v/text()" name="Name" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
                <property expression="//f[2]/v/text()" name="Age" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
                
                <!--  Frame payload for Service Call -->
               
                <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
                    <format>
                        <Envelope xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
                            <Body>
                                <Request xmlns="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">
                                    <Name>$1</tenant>
                                    <Age>$2</source>
                                </Request>
                            </Body>
                        </Envelope>
                    </format>
                    <args>
                        <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('Name')"/>
                        <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('Age')"/>
                        
                    </args>
                </payloadFactory>
                
                <call>
                    <endpoint>
                        <http method="post" uri-template="http://localhost:8281/jsonapi">
                            <timeout>
                                <duration>60000</duration>
                            </timeout>
                            <suspendOnFailure>
                                <errorCodes>-1</errorCodes>
                                <initialDuration>0</initialDuration>
                                <progressionFactor>1.0</progressionFactor>
                                <maximumDuration>0</maximumDuration>
                            </suspendOnFailure>
                            <markForSuspension>
                                <retriesBeforeSuspension>0</retriesBeforeSuspension>
                            </markForSuspension>
                        </http>
                    </endpoint>
                </call>
            </sequence>
        </target>
    </iterate>
    <log level="custom">
        <property name="INFO: " value="process is Completed"/>
    </log>
```

- As per above added sample request there are two iteration should happened since it has two elements. and Finally log outside iterator should get printed ie only one time.
- But if you could see below wso2logs, we can able to understood that log outside iterator also getting printed for each iteration even though it is placed outside of iterate mediator.

**WSO2 Log:**

```
[2023-03-14 18:10:01,289] []  INFO - LogMediator JSONAPI***  = Called
[2023-03-14 18:10:01,289] []  INFO - LogMediator INFO:  = process is Completed
[2023-03-14 18:10:01,305] []  INFO - LogMediator JSONAPI***  = Called
[2023-03-14 18:10:01,305] []  INFO - LogMediator INFO:  = process is Completed
```

- Placed `Send` mediator also instead of `call`, outsequence flow executed on each Iteration rather than one time. ie log added in outsequence section getting printed on each iteration.
- I tried some other ways like Iterator with other params like `sequential=true` , `continueParent=true` etc, none of them resolves this issue.

May I know Why this weird behavior of Iterator? how can we resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate Mediator should always be coupled with an [Aggregate Mediator](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI660/Aggregate+Mediator). In the Aggregate Mediator, you can specify a Complete Condition. Once the Complete Condition is met it would come to the OnComplete block and move along the integration.

Following is an example where Aggregate is in the out sequence with Send Mediator.

```xml
<proxy name="SplitAggregateProxy">
        <target>
            <inSequence>
                <iterate expression="//m0:getQuote/m0:request" preservePayload="true"
                         attachPath="//m0:getQuote"
                         xmlns:m0="http://services.samples">
                    <target>
                        <sequence>
                            <send>
                                <endpoint>
                                    <address
                                        uri="http://localhost:9000/services/SimpleStockQuoteService"/>
                                </endpoint>
                            </send>
                        </sequence>
                    </target>
                </iterate>
            </inSequence>
            <outSequence>
                <aggregate>
                    <onComplete expression="//m0:getQuoteResponse"
                                xmlns:m0="http://services.samples">
                        <send/>
                    </onComplete>
                </aggregate>
            </outSequence>
        </target>
</proxy>
```

Another example.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sequence name="iterate-aggregate-example" trace="disable" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
  <property description="countRequests" expression="count(//Account)"
    name="countRequests" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
  <iterate expression="//Account" id="IterateAccountCreate"
sequential="true">
    <target>
      <sequence>
        <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
          <format>
            <echo:echoString xmlns_echo="http://echo.services.core.carbon.wso2.org">
              <in xmlns="">$1</in>
            </echo:echoString>
          </format>
          <args>
            <arg evaluator="xml" expression="//Account/text()"/>
          </args>
        </payloadFactory>
        <property action="remove" description="TRANSPORT_HEADERS"
          name="TRANSPORT_HEADERS" scope="axis2"/>
        <property description="OperationName" name="OperationName"
          scope="default" type="STRING" value="echoString"/>
        <header action="remove" name="To" scope="default"/>
        <header name="Action" scope="default" value="urn:echoString"/>
        <header name="SOAPAction" scope="transport" value="urn:echoString"/>
        <log category="DEBUG" description="***Request***">
          <property expression="$body" name="request"/>
        </log>
        <call>
          <endpoint key="echo"/>
        </call>
        <log category="DEBUG" description="***Response***" separator="***Response***">
          <property expression="$body" name="create_instanties_response"/>
        </log>
      </sequence>
    </target>
  </iterate>
  <aggregate description="" id="IterateAccountCreate">
    <completeCondition timeout="10">
      <messageCount max="{get-property('countRequests')}" min="{get
property('countRequests')}"/>
    </completeCondition>
    <onComplete expression="//ns:echoStringResponse" xmlns_ns="http://echo.services.core.carbon.wso2.org">
      <log description="***aggregated***" separator="***aggregated***">
        <property expression="$body" name="aggregated_body"/>      </log>
    </onComplete>
  </aggregate>
</sequence>
```

Here is a good blog to refer. https://www.yenlo.com/blogs/iterate-aggregate-call-mediator-wso2-esb/

In your case, if you don't want to count the messages etc. You can have a simple aggregator like below. Note the ID of the Aggregator should match the ID of your Iterate Mediator.

```xml
<aggregate id="BigQID">
        <completeCondition timeout="30">
            <messageCount max="-1" min="-1"/>
        </completeCondition>
        <onComplete enclosingElementProperty="Result" expression="$body/*">
            <log level="custom">
               <property name="INFO: " value="process is Completed"/>
            </log>
        </onComplete>
</aggregate>
```

Comment: Hi @ycr,
Thanks for your suggestion. Iterate with Aggregate mediator resolved issue. I have added answer too

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @ycr , Added `Iterator` with `Aggregator` which resolves above reported issue.

```
 <property name="result" scope="default">
            <result xmlns=""/>
        </property>
```

After Iterator, added above mentioned `property` for enclosing aggregated elements.

```
<!--  Iterate over JSON Array Elements -->
    <iterate expression="$body//rows" id="BigQID">
        <target>
            <sequence>
                <property expression="//f[1]/v/text()" name="Name" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
                <property expression="//f[2]/v/text()" name="Age" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
                
                <!--  Frame payload for Service Call -->
               
                <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
                    <format>
                        <Envelope xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
                            <Body>
                                <Request xmlns="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">
                                    <Name>$1</tenant>
                                    <Age>$2</source>
                                </Request>
                            </Body>
                        </Envelope>
                    </format>
                    <args>
                        <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('Name')"/>
                        <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('Age')"/>
                        
                    </args>
                </payloadFactory>
                
                <call>
                    <endpoint>
                        <http method="post" uri-template="http://localhost:8281/jsonapi">
                            <timeout>
                                <duration>60000</duration>
                            </timeout>
                            <suspendOnFailure>
                                <errorCodes>-1</errorCodes>
                                <initialDuration>0</initialDuration>
                                <progressionFactor>1.0</progressionFactor>
                                <maximumDuration>0</maximumDuration>
                            </suspendOnFailure>
                            <markForSuspension>
                                <retriesBeforeSuspension>0</retriesBeforeSuspension>
                            </markForSuspension>
                        </http>
                    </endpoint>
                </call>
            </sequence>
        </target>
    </iterate>
    <property name="result" scope="default">
        <result xmlns=""/>
    </property>
    <!--  Aggregate for collecting service response in order to identify target count -->
    <aggregate id="BigQID">
        <completeCondition>
            <messageCount max="-1" min="-1"/>
        </completeCondition>
        <onComplete aggregateElementType="root" enclosingElementProperty="result" expression="$body/*[1]">
            <log level="custom">
                <property name="ON Aggregate SEQ" value="called***"/>
                <property expression="fn:count(//*[local-name()='UpdatedRowCount'])" name="*********BigQueryETL-Emite_CDW-TargetCount:: "/>
            </log>
        </onComplete>
    </aggregate>
    <log level="custom">
        <property name="INFO: " value="process is Completed"/>
    </log>
```